# Why can't echo see sourced environment variable from a shell script?

Tags: echo, source

I have the following shell script:

**cron_job.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/ec2-user/src/.config
```

I use it like this `./cron_job.sh`

when I echo `$DB_NAME`, which is included in the .config, I see nothing. When I cut copy paste, the source command, `source /home/ec2-user/src/.config` then `echo $DB_NAME` I see the value. What is going on here conceptually? and How do I use man pages to learn what is going on?

**/home/ec2-user/src/.config**

```
cat /home/ec2-user/src/.config
export DB_NAME="market"
```

**echo_vars.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $DB_NAME
```

**shell**

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-94 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2 (Ootpa)
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-94 ~]$ echo "$SHELL"
/bin/bash
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-94 ~]$ ./cron_job.sh
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-94 ~]$ ./echo_vars.sh
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-94 ~]$
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-94 ~]$ echo $DB_NAME
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-94 ~]$
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-94 ~]$ source /home/ec2-user/src/goldbase/.config
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-94 ~]$ ./echo_vars.sh
app_db
```

Comment: Where exactly are you running `echo $DB_PASS`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us an example that we can run and reproduce the issue. We have no idea what is in your `.config`, what `echo` command you run, where you run it (in a script? Manually? In the same session? Different session?). We can't help you if we need to guess what you are doing. We need a series of commands that we can use to test.

Comment: done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new shell to run `./cron_job.sh`. It sources the other file, then exits.

On exit all variable state is lost.

Export only exports to self and children. So state is lost when the process dies. Using source allows a script to read a file in the same process, thus the variables remain. However they are still lost when this process dies.

If you put the echo in the file under the `source`, then it will work.

---

Note it is not echo that sees the environment variable (it could, but it is just not interested). The variable is expanded by the shell.

Note shell script names should not end with a `.sh`. It will cause problems in another day.

Comment: Note that naming conventions for shell scripts are just conventions.

Comment: @Kusalananda it will work fine, but one day you will have a python or go compiled program called `zzzzz.sh`, or you will have to fix every script that calls it.

Comment: Umm... why? Filenames are arbitrary after all.

Comment: @Kusalananda You are of course correct. Therefore name files `a`, `b`, `c` … `z`, `aa`, `ab` … This will save on typing and they are as good as any other name.